# How to apply a GAM function by group for every individual

Tags: r, group-by, model, prediction, gam

I have a tree growth database containing the number of cells in every growth stage (enlarging, thickening, mature) for every DOY (Day of the year) for every tree and every year (6 different trees per year, 10 years, 60 trees in total). The database looks like this (simplified):

```
 Year Tree DOY Enlarging Thickening Mature
  2012  25  80    0         0          0
  2012  25  87    1         0          0
  2012  25  94    4         0          0
  2012  25  103   5         1          0
  2012  25  111   3         3          0
  2012  25  119   1         4          1
  2012  25  127   1         5          3
  2012  30  80    0         0          0
  2012  30  87    2         0          0
  2012  30  94    5         1          0
  2012  30  103   7         3          1
  2012  30  111   4         6          2
  2012  30  119   3         7          5
  2012  30  127   1         8          7
  2012  43  80    0         0          0
  2012  43  87    0         0          0
  2012  43  94    2         0          0
  etc.
```

I would like to apply a GAM function to obtain predictions about **when** does every growth stage start and finish for **every tree, every year**, and also understand the growth curves and pattern every stage follows. The model I use it's just a simple GAM between every growth phase number of cells (enlarging, thickening, mature) and the day of the year it occurs:

```
Enlarging <- gam(Enlarging ~ s(DOY), data=datosSTD, quasipoisson, gamma=1, min.sp=0.01)  
Thickening <- gam(Thickening ~ s(DOY), data=datosSTD, quasipoisson, gamma=1, min.sp=0.01)  
Mature <-gam(Mature ~ s(DOY), data=datosSTD, quasipoisson, gamma=1, min.sp=0.01)
```

My problem is that I am unable to apply this GAM model to every individual tree, or even apply it for the yearly average of trees. For example, I tried using dplyr with the enlarging phase:

```
    Enlarging <- df %>%
      group_by(Tree, Year)%>%
      do(gam_enlarging = gam(Enlarging ~ s(DOY), data = ., quasipoisson, gamma = 1, min.sp = 0.01))%>%
      ungroup
```

which gives me a list with the coefficients, residuals and **fitted values** among other data. But when I try to obtain the fitted values of the model for every tree I get an error:

> fitted.enlarging <- data.frame(c(sapply(Enlarging$gam_enlarging,
> fitted)))
>
> *Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows:
> 19, 18, 23, 15, 26, 22, 29, 21*

I tried using the function *predict*, but I get a different error:

```
predicted.enlarging <- as.vector(predict(Enlarging,  data.frame(DOY),type="response"))
```

> *Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"*

I was thinking about using a loop, but honestly I don't think I have the knowledge to do that yet. I'm still learning basic R. I just need to know when does every growth phase start (nº Enlarging cells>1) and ends (nº Enlarging cells<0) for every tree, every year, and be able to plot a representation of the growth stage curve pattern. If possible, I would like to use the *dplyr* package to group my data and process it since it's the package I'm more familiar with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to fit each tree/year combination separately? Would a single model (per response variable) not be preferable so you can draw power from the population of trees/years? We cover this in our paper on HGAMs: https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876 Fitting a single model per tree/year combination would solve the problem of having to deal with all these GAM objects too

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson! To be honest, I used a GAM model because I have trees of different size class and I was curious to check their individual growth patterns every single day of the year to see if there are differences among old trees and young ones. But now that I think of it, for the approach I want I'm not interested in differences among size classes, so maybe it would be more appropiate to fit a model for all trees during every year to see the general tendencies. Now I'm a bit confused about what to do.

Comment: @DavidAlmagro If you have a variable `size_class` you could include that in the model if you think trees within a size class have a similar growth patterns plus their own individual pattern around the size class pattern. So, you don't have to give up on that idea if you go down the single-model HGAM route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set of dataframe rearrangements with {dplyr} and {tidyr} allow you to group your data, nest them (i. e. populate a dataframe 'cell' with subsets of data), apply arbitrary functions (like `gam`), and finally unnest the thing again.

It's probably best explained with an example. Using your data (in that case only one combination of Tree and Year, but use it on your whole data as desired):

your example data:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L), Tree = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), DOY = c(80L, 
87L, 94L, 103L, 111L, 119L, 127L), Enlarging = c(0L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Thickening = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
    Mature = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
7L))
```

required libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gam)
```

- reshape the data from *wide* to *long* format, i. e. stack `Count` by growth status groups:

```
df_long <- 
  df |>
  pivot_longer(Enlarging:Mature,
               names_to = 'Growth_Phase',
               values_to = 'Count'
               )
```

```
#> df_long |> head(3)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
   Year  Tree   DOY Growth_Phase Count
  <int> <int> <int> <chr>        <int>
1  2012    25    80 Enlarging        0
2  2012    25    80 Thickening       0
3  2012    25    80 Mature           0
```

- nest by `Year`, `Tree` and `Growth_Phase`:

```
df_nested <- 
  df_long |>
  nest_by(Year, Tree, Growth_Phase)
```

column `data` of the nested dataframe contains one dataframe per row (= unique combination of `Year` x `Tree` x `Growth_Phase`):

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Rowwise:  Year, Tree, Growth_Phase
   Year  Tree Growth_Phase               data
  <int> <int> <chr>        <list<tibble[,2]>>
1  2012    25 Enlarging               [7 x 2]
2  2012    25 Mature                  [7 x 2]
3  2012    25 Thickening              [7 x 2]
```

- fit a GAM per combination (remember to return the GAM or any other not atomic result as a `list`, so it can be accomodated by a single cell of the main dataframe):

```
df_with_gam <- 
  df_nested |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(the_gam = list(
           gam(Count ~ s(DOY), 
               data = data, quasipoisson, gamma = 1, min.sp = 0.01)  
         ),
         Fitted = list(predict(the_gam, type = 'response'))
         )
```

```
> df_with_gam
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Rowwise: 
   Year  Tree Growth_Phase               data the_gam Fitted   
  <int> <int> <chr>        <list<tibble[,2]>> <list>  <list>   
1  2012    25 Enlarging               [7 x 2] <Gam>   <dbl [7]>
2  2012    25 Mature                  [7 x 2] <Gam>   <dbl [7]>
3  2012    25 Thickening              [7 x 2] <Gam>   <dbl [7]>
```

- select and unnest the desired columns again:

```
df_with_gam |>
  select(Year:Growth_Phase, data, Fitted) |>
  unnest_longer(c('data', 'Fitted')) |>
  unnest_wider(data)
```

```
+ # A tibble: 21 x 7
    Year  Tree Growth_Phase   DOY Count   Fitted Fitted_id
   <int> <int> <chr>        <int> <int>    <dbl> <chr>    
 1  2012    25 Enlarging       80     0 1.30e- 1 1        
 2  2012    25 Enlarging       87     1 9.71e- 1 2        
 3  2012    25 Enlarging       94     4 3.79e+ 0 3        
 4  2012    25 Enlarging      103     5 5.07e+ 0 4        
 5  2012    25 Enlarging      111     3 2.87e+ 0 5        
 6  2012    25 Enlarging      119     1 1.26e+ 0 6        
 7  2012    25 Enlarging      127     1 8.95e- 1 7        
 8  2012    25 Mature          80     0 5.94e-11 1        
 9  2012    25 Mature          87     0 3.23e-13 2        
10  2012    25 Mature          94     0 4.53e-15 3        
# ... with 11 more rows
```

- `filter`, `pivot_wider`, `arrange` (= sort) etc. as desired ...
- quick control, `df_result` being your resulting dataframe after above manipulations:

```
library(ggplot2)

df_result |>
  ggplot() +
     geom_point(aes(Count, Fitted)) +
     facet_wrap(~ Growth_Phase)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for asking. This was really helpful, the most helpful answer I got so far. I have another question, I've been trying for days. How can I predict growth cells of every growth stage for each DOY of the year (for every tree, every year) using GAM? I wanted to create a new dataframe called 'DOY' with days from 1,2,3... to 365 and then use it as newdata' when using the *predict* function, but I'm unable and don't know in which step of the proccess should I do it. Thank you so much, I hope you can answer me because I'm desperate @I_O

Comment: I am sorry, but I know too little about modelling in the time domain (time series etc.) to help you out. Intuitively I'd say you'll gain deeper insight into which environmental conditions shape your data by subtracting seasonality and longer trends - for which you need to pick a suitable modelling technique (probably other than GAM). You might ask the statistic ninjas over at crossvalidated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for a generic solution and return here for its R-specific implementation. Don't despair ;-)